# Reverse a string in php without using any string function

Tags: php

In yesterday Interview I was asked that how to reverse a string with out using any string function like strrev() or strlen(). I found this example on website but it gives error.is it possible to do this without strlen().

> Uninitialized string offset: -1 in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php on line xx

```
$string = "ZEESHAN";

$i =0;

while(($string[$i])!=null){

        $i++;

}

$i--;

while(($string[$i])!=null){

        echo $string[$i];

$i--;

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$string = 'zeeshan';
$reverse = '';
$i = 0;
while(!empty($string[$i])){ 
      $reverse = $string[$i].$reverse; 
      $i++;
}
echo $reverse;
```

Comment: It's perfectly memory optimistic solution to php 7.2 , Thanks. man.https://3v4l.org/eLttS

Comment: It will be better to use `isset($string[$i])` for check character, because if  the line contain a digit `0`, the script stops.

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
$string = "ZEESHAN";

$j = 0;
while(!empty($string[$j])) {
   $j++;
}

for($i = ($j-1); $i >= 0; $i--) {
    echo $string[$i];
}
```

**Output**

```
NAHSEEZ
```

Comment: I cannot use [strlen ](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) as it is a string function.

Comment: I hope you can use `empty`. @ShakunChaudhary

Comment: did u run this example on ur pc coz I am getting error **
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 7 in D:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\example.php on line 10
NAHSEEZ**

Comment: This is your output : 7NAHSEEZ

Comment: @ShakunChaudhary Submit that page again.

Comment: It because sougata has echoed `$j` too within his link @ShakunChaudhary

Comment: It's because you have to subtract 1 to $j in the end, because in this case we have 7 chars, but since we are looping throught an array we must begin at index 0

Comment: I am running the same code on my xampp.but I an getting notice.**Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 7 in D:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\example.php on line 11
NAHSEEZ**

Comment: @ShakunChaudhary That is not the solution. Have updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple logic for string reversal

```
$str = 'ABCD';
$strReversed = '';
$length = strlen($str);
for($i=$length-1; $i >= 0; $i--){
    $strReversed .= $str[$i];
}
echo $strReversed;
```

Comment: you have used strlen string function but we have restriction for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with `count_chars` and `array_sum`

```
<?php

$string = "ZEESHAN";
$count=array_sum(count_chars($string));

for($i=$count -1 ;$i>=0;$i--){
        echo $string[$i];
}
?>
```

If you dont want any php string function you can try this way with `krsort` and `array`:

```
<?php

$string = "ZEESHAN";
$arr = array();
$i=0;
while(isset($string[$i])){
        $arr[$i] = $string[$i];
        $i++;
}
krsort($arr);
$final = implode("",$arr);

var_dump($final);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while` and `for` loop like as

```
$string = "ZEESHAN";
$reverse = "";
$j = 0;
while(isset($string[$j])){
    $j++;
}

for($i = $j - 1; $i >= 0; $i--){
    $reverse .= $string[$i];
}
echo $reverse;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Program for reversing a string
<?php
class str_rev{
    public function Revese_Str($string){
        $reverse = '';
        $i=0;
        while(!empty($string[$i])){ 
          $reverse = $string[$i].$reverse; 
          $i++;
        }
        return $reverse;
    }
}
$object = new str_rev();
echo $object->Revese_Str('Ayush Jain');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code to resolve this problem.

```
<?php

$string = "ZEESHAN";

$i =0;

while(!empty($string[$i])){ 
       
        $i++;
}

$i--;

while(!empty($string[$i])){     

        echo $string[$i];

$i--;

}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this

```
$string = "heya";
$i = strlen("heya") - 1;
$newStr = "";

while($i >= 0) {
    $newStr .= $string[$i];
    $i--;
}
echo $newStr; // output: ayeh
```

Comment: but you are using strlen function which is string function

Answer (score -1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <center>
      <form action="#" method="get">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="txt"/>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        <br><br>
      </form>
```

---

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["submit"])) {
    $name = $_GET["txt"];
    for ($i = 0; isset($name[$i]); $i++) {
        $j = $i;
    }
    for ($k = $j; isset($name[$k]); $k--) {
        echo $name[$k];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look the below code: Reverse the string

```
$str = 'abcdefg';
    $reverseString = '';
    for($i=strlen($str);$i<=strlen($str);$i--){
      $reverseString .= $str[$i];
    if($i==0)
    break;
    }

    echo $reverseString;
```

The above code output is:

```
gfedcba
```

Comment: But you are using strlen() function which is string function.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$string = 'ZEESHAN';
$reverse = '';
$i = 0;
while(!empty($string[$i])){
    $reverse = $string[$i].$reverse;
    $i++;
}
echo $reverse;
?>
```

Check complete post: https://www.troposal.com/reverse-string-without-function-php/