# how to reverse a string in PHP without using inbuilt function?

Tags: php

To reverse a string in php
Here is my logic:

```
$string="abcd";
$reverse="";
for($i=count($string);$i<=0;$i--)
{
  $reverse.=$string[$i];
}

echo $reverse;
```

Comment: `strrev() ` try use that

Comment: Let me explain your code in words: let $i = 4, if the statement 4 (value of $i now) < = 0 is true, then run the command `$reverse.=$string[$i];`, then set $i = 3 then go check the statement above still true. Do you see the problem there?

Comment: @jack: OP states he/she does not want to use inbuilt function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse a string in php without using any string function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415889/reverse-a-string-in-php-without-using-any-string-function)

Answer (score 2):

Just a couple of problems here. FIrst, you want to use [`strlen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) instead of count to get the number of characters in the string. Second, your operator is off in the for loop, you're counting down, you you want to see if `$i` is greater than or equal.

```
<?php
$string='abcd';
$reverse='';
for($i=strlen($string);$i>=0;$i--)
{
    $reverse.=$string[$i];
}

echo $reverse.PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the split string into an array, and then traverse and concatenate it.

```php
function revstr($str)
{
    if (strlen($str) <= 1) return $str;
 
    $newstr  = '';
    $str2arr = str_split($str,1);
    foreach ($str2arr as $word) {
        $newstr = $word.$newstr;
    }
 
    return $newstr;
}
```

In addition to this, there is another method, which is to use recursion to do.

```php
function revstr($str)
{
    if (strlen($str) <= 1) return $str;
 
    $newstr = '';
    $newstr .= substr($str,-1).revstr(substr($str,0,strlen($str)-1));
 
    return $newstr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `strlen` function

```
<?php
$str = "abcd";
$i = 0;
$strArr = [];
while(isset($str[$i])){
    $strArr[] = $str[$i];
    $i++;
}
$newStr = '';
$i--;
while($i>=0){
    $newStr .= $strArr[$i];
    $i--;
}
print_r($newStr);
```

Demo Link : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2b4de1d1f3d85bc4a59e15700414a5ffa654fef